# Bad Parameter error when deleting page in Adobe PDF (Acrobat 9.0)

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

When deleting or adding pages in an Adobe PDF created file using Adobe Acrobat 9.0 I am receiving a "Bad Parameter" error. This can be resolved by creating a new PDF of the PDF by using the Adobe PDF printer, but that is not a workable solution as it decreases the quality of the document.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution that retains bookmarks (it worked for me).

(I'm using Acrobat 8)

1. Use the "Combine Files" feature to combine the problem file with some other PDF (doesn't matter what the file is, though you might choose a small PDF that doesn't have this issue). I combined the files with the problem file first, followed by the additional PDF; I didn't want to chance messing up the bookmarks - but I don't know that the order matters.
2. When done, save the resulting file.
3. Open the saved file and you should be able to delete the added PDF pages, and for that matter, you should be able to add/delete/insert pages to the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 2):

In the dialog that says 'bad parameter error' press control when clicking OK. This sometimes gives a more informative message.

The basic problem is that there is something wrong with the PDF file, Acrobat doesn't bother to tell you about this normally, but instead silently ignores the error. Acrobat does this a *lot* and is a major reason why there are a lot of technically invalid PDF files around 'it must be OK because Acrobat can read it'....

By 'refrying' the PDF (printing the content to a new PDF file) you are getting rid of a lot of elements of the PDF and since you are only printing what Acrobat displayd, the resulting PDF file will be fine.

However its not possible to tell you what's wrong with the PDF file without seeing it. You *could* try using another tool to manipulate the PDF file, it might fix it in the process. For example ou could use GhostScript to convert the PDF to PDF, the default settigns should work well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and following solution Worked for me.

- Click on File then Print
- Save it as Adobe PDF
- Close and Reopen the new saved file.
- Now try to delete the page.

It worked for me.